# Eddy Currents in Metal Implants

Tags: electric-current, metals, induction

Related: [Why is stainless steel a poor conductor of electricity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92960/why-is-stainless-steel-a-poor-conductor-of-electricity)
I recently had a metal implant, and I'm psyching myself out- should I be considered at all with eddy currents in the implant? I feel like the steel must be somewhat of a better conductor than my body, indeed in the above question it appears to be so. Couldn't eddy currents get painful?

Comment: How big a changing magnetic flux do you figure to encounter? Does your job take you near powerful electromagnets or do you expect to get a MRI? This is rather a special case problem.

Comment: I'm currently a college student-I might be a around a synchrotron in the next few years, but I'm also a hypochondriac and I wonder if it would be worth it to go through another surgery to get the plate out.

Comment: MRI's are a no go, right?

Comment: Talk to the tech about the MRI. They may be able to control the ramping to a be slow enough. If the tech is not sure, get an opinion from the machines manufacturer. A high field as such is not a problem unless it puts too much stress on the body.

Comment: Should I not be concerned with the plate then? Currents, or magnets?

Comment: Why would eddy currents get painful ? Steel is a much better conductor than human body so if there are any eddy currents then they would be in the plate only. Also steel is a poor conductor as compared to other conductors so the magnitude of current will also be low which means very less heating effect. I suppose you may feel hot, but there is no reason to feel pain !

Comment: Well wouldn't heat be kind of cruddy in your body?